# Regex to get a string after a character

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have strings like `A1234-111`,`D890-222`,`A456-333` etc...
How do I use regex to get everything after `-` character; *the right hand side*.

Comment: where is your current code failing?

Comment: Hint: for the example at hand you might get away with a substring function.

Comment: there are at least 5 ways to do that....

Comment: @Kent With 5 possibly tending to infinity.

Answer (score 3):

Regex shines by being able to name and extract the matches (*In regex lingo naming the match capture groups*).

Here I have named both sides within the pattern, once acquired simply extract from the one needed.

```
var data = "A1234-111";
var pattern = @"(?<Pre>[^-]+)-(?<Post>.+)";

var mtch = Regex.Match(data, pattern);

Console.WriteLine ("Pre is {0} and Post is {1}", mtch.Groups["Pre"], mtch.Groups["Post"]);

// Result
// Pre is A1234 and Post is 111
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the regex

```
(?<=-)\d+
```

`(?<=...)` is a lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

Replace anything before the `-` with empty string.

```
string input = " A1234-111";
input = Regex.Replace(input, @".*?-", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to split twice:

```
foreach (string s in myString.Split(','))
{
    string afterHyphen = s.Split('-')[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need regex, do you?

```
List<string> result = input.Split(',')
    .Select(s => s.Split('-').Last())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to search whole string, use:

```
(?[A-Za-z]\d+\-(\d+),)+
```

First group is noncapturing to group items between commas, second group is capturing to actually match your numbers.

If you need to search strings delimited by comma separately, then better use String.Split, or:

```
[A-Za-z]\d+\-(\d+)
```

You can replace `[A-Za-z]\d` with `\w`.

Answer (score 0):

Using C#, you must include the System.Text.RegularExpressions library and then run a match:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
  Regex rx = new Regex(@"[^\-]\-(.*)");
  string s = "A1234-111";
  Match m = rx.Match(s);
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Match is " + m.Groups[1].Value);
...
```

I know you asked about Regex, but you can run a split on the text, as long as the pattern is the same:

```
string[] parts = s.Split(new char[] { '-' });
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Split Match is " + parts[1]);
```

Whatever works best.
:)